# Is it possible to use LIKE or " = " on two columns with SOME sharing values?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

In my database I have the following tables:

```
CUS
Name varchar(20)
CustomerID varchar(8)

PET
Name varchar(20)
PetID varchar (8)

CUS Table
| Name | CustomerID  |
----------------------
| John | AC001       |

PET Table
| Name     | PetID   |
----------------------
| Snuffles | AC001-01|
| Puffles  | AC001-02|
```

You can see that Snuffles & Puffles belongs to John, as their PetID's are the same as John's CustomerID but with an additional 3 characters.

**My question:**

Is there a way for me to use " = " or " LIKE " on the columns :

```
SELECT CUS.Name , PET.Name, PetID
FROM CUS, PET
WHERE PetID = CustomerID;
```

so that I get a similar result to:

```
WHERE PetID LIKE 'AC%' AND CustomerID LIKE 'AC%';
```

where the table would show:

```
| Name     | Name     |  PetID   |
-----------------------------------
| John     | Snuffles | AC001-01 |
| John     | Puffles  | AC001-02 |
```

without having to explicitly write down wildcard conditions for each owner/pet.

Comment: While you can do this, it would probably be better to split the `PetID` field into two columns.

Comment: it would probably be easier to store a numeric id instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could use `LIKE` as join condition:

```
SELECT CUS.Name, PET.Name, PetID
FROM CUS
JOIN PET
  ON PetId LIKE CONCAT(CustomerId,'%');
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=808d15106dd280c7540835a6bc72c03f)**